# how does Trace route packet work

Tags: traceroute

I am  fining difficulties understanding trace route command
how does trace route works from source to a destination?
how the routers reply to the source with their IP?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`traceroute` works by sending ICMP echo requests or fake UDP datagrams towards the destination (probes), starting with TTL set to 1 and increasing one by one. On each router/hop on the way, the packet TTL is decreased when it's forwarded. When TTL reaches 0 the packet is dropped.

The hop where the TTL ran out sends an ICMP `Time Exceeded` (=TTL expired) back to the source. The `traceroute` tool collects these ICMP messages and  displays them in a table together with their return times and the ICMP packet source.

Note that ICMP packets have a very low processing and forwarding priority. It is quite possible that a hop drops the expired probe packet silently, without bothering with ICMP, or another hop on the way back drops the message due to congestion or overload.

Also, the IP address that is returned to and displayed by `traceroute` might be a different IP address than that of the router's interface where your packet was received on. Some routers may even return a private IP address from RFC 1918 that doesn't make sense to you at all.

Comment: Note that not all traceroute implementations use UDP. Also note that the destination host does not send an ICMP time exceeded.

Comment: @hertitu Thx - yes, I was trying to keep it simple.